# Como alternar entre o Java 8 e o 11 no Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, path, jdk

Eu fiz há alguns dias atrás a transição do Windows 7 para o Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, e tive algumas dificuldades no processo. Bem, vamos aos detalhes.

Instalei o JDK 11 através do comando a seguir:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-openjdk`

Porém eu preciso do JDK 8 para alguns projetos de faculdade. Como eu posso alternar entre o openJDK 8 e o 11? No Windows eu fazia modificando a variável de sistema `PATH`, então imagino que deve haver algo semelhante...

Comment: Uso o [sdkman.io](https://sdkman.io/) para Java e outras ferramentas e facilita bastante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você atualizar o versão do java que você quer utilizar. Para listar todas as versões instaladas use o comando

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

Para atualizar basta digitar o seguinte:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /caminho/para/versao/java
```

Onde `/caminho/para/versao/java` pode ser, por exemplo: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: Usei o seguinte comando: `sudo update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, mas o Terminal me deu a seguinte resposta: `update-java-alternatives: file does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/.java-8-openjdk-amd64.jinfo`. Tentei diversas coisas, inclusive direcionar todo o caminho para o arquivo `jinfo` de dentro da pasta `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin`, mas não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, tem alguma ideia? Obrigado.

Comment: Quando você roda o comando `java -version`, o que ele retorna?

Comment: `openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, ele já alterou para a versão 11. Esse erro, pelo que eu pesquisei, é quando um módulo ainda não está suportando o `update-java-alternatives`

Comment: E, como ele não está suportando ainda, existe algo que eu possa fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Corrigindo a Resposta do @Felipe Avelar

1° Passo:
sudo update-java-alternatives --list

2° Passo:
sudo update-alternatives --config java

3° Passo:
Seleciona o numero e aperte Enter

4° Passo:
Verificar se atualizou com o comando
java --version

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).